# SQL Stored Procedure String Search via Passed Parameter and Using 'LIKE' query

Tags: mysql, sql, search, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will search my table using the parameter passed by the user as it calls the SP. I would like to use the 'LIKE' query for this. So far, this is what I got.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SEARCH_STUDENT`$$
CREATE
    PROCEDURE `test`.`SEARCH_STUDENT`(_textInput VARCHAR(10))
    BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM records WHERE `lastname` LIKE '%'+_textInput+'%';
    END$$
```

but im getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Search varchar(10);
    SET @Search=_textInput;
    SELECT * FROM records WHERE `last' at line 10
```

What I get from google are samples with fixed string to be searched. Mine depends on what the user will input in the textbox. Thanks a lot for any help in advanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it now. Thanks to this link.

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?620319-MySQL-Stored-Procedure-LIKE-and-a-string-variable-the-combination-don-t-work

The sql CONCAT function is the answer. Here's my code now:

```
CREATE
    PROCEDURE `test`.`SEARCH_STUDENT`(_textInput VARCHAR(10))
    BEGIN

    -- sELECT * FROM records WHERE `lastname` LIKE '%' + _textInput;
    SELECT * FROM records WHERE `lastname` LIKE CONCAT('%',_textInput,'%');

    END$$
```

Comment: And since your stored procedure is one-statement SP you can ditch `BEGIN...END` block and you won't need to change `DELIMITER`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`SEARCH_STUDENT`(in _textInput VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    -- SELECT * FROM records WHERE `lastname` LIKE '%' + _textInput;
    SELECT * FROM records WHERE `lastname` LIKE CONCAT('%',_textInput,'%');
END$$
```

put in

```
\`test\`.\`SEARCH_STUDENT\`(in _textInput VARCHAR(10))
```

other wise out will not show properly